# Print with POS printers using android built-in print framework

Tags: android, printing

Most of companies producing POS printers (or label printers) which connects to mobile devices provide SDK for developers to send data to the printer.

Is it possible to use android default print framework (added in android 4.4) for sending data to these kind of printers?
(writing render codes is much easier!)

Answer (score 0):

If the printer manufacturer offers a compatible print driver app for Android, yes. Otherwise, no.

IOW, you need to ask the printer manufacturer.

Note that this is not unique to POS printers — the same thing is true of every printer. Either there is an Android print driver app, or there is not.

Comment: Thanks. So, how the paper size is managed? (I mean in printadapter paper size is defined and render code run based on it)

Comment: @user2912553: If the printer does not support one of [Android's media sizes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/PrintAttributes.MediaSize.html), my guess is that there is no print driver for it.